# Для header в браузере добавляются непрописанные в стилях отступы

Tags: html, css

На сайте почему-то присутствуют отступы от header, хотя я их не прописывал. Не понимаю в чём проблема. На остальных страницах сайта отступы такие же.

```
header {
    box-sizing: border-box;/**/
    padding: 10px;/**/
    font-family: Helvetica;/**/
    font-size: 100%; /**/
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #c00000;/**/
    color: white;/**/
    width: 100%;/**/
}
```

[image: страница сайта]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Пока что ничего не понятно, ждём [mcve]

Comment: Посмотрите в средствах разработки в браузере, откуда появляются эти маргины, и от этого уже отталкивайтесь

Comment: Браузер по-умолчанию имеет определенные user agent stylesheet. Это стили предопределенные браузером.